# Interpretation of the integral

Tags: integration, analysis

My question is about the interpretation of the integral. Say I have a state vector $v(t)$ that gives at each point in time $t\geq0$ the number of workers I have. Now the number of workers change continously over time. Moreover I have a rate $\rho$ at which they produce something, let's say rings. It is intuitively absolutely clear that the total amount of rings produced in the timespan $[0,\infty)$ is given by the integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\rho v(t)dt
\end{align}
I am looking for an easy but mathematical correct explanation of this fact. How would you explain it to someone who was recently introduced to Analysis 1?

Comment: The rate at which the rings are being produced at time $t$ is $r'(t) = \rho v(t)$, so the total number of rings produced since time zero is $\int_0^\infty r'(t)dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's easier if you think in terms of units. Specifically, $[\rho]$ = rings / (worker × time-unit).

Now, suppose $v(t) \equiv v$ constant. Just from the units, you may see that the number of rings produced within an interval $[t_1,t_2]$ is given by $$(t_2 - t_1)\rho v.$$

After that, you might intuitively pursue that if, $v(t)$ is piece-wise constant on the partition $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = T$, then the number of rings is

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(t_{i+1} - t_i)\rho v_i.$$

If you made it up to this point, the remainder is just limits.

Answer (score 0):

You may run into issues with the improper integral "explaining" convergence. But for 
$$
\int_0^t\,\rho v(\tau) \, d\tau
$$
we can think of $\rho v(\tau)$ as "rings produced at infinitesimal time $\tau$" (workers times number of rings per worker) and the integral as the accumulation of rings from time 0 to time $t$.

The integral is always an accumulation of something, in this case rings since the "dimensions" of $\rho v$ is $\frac{\text{rings}}{\text{worker}}\times\text{worker}=\text{rings}$, so the integral is the accumulation of rings.